# How can I pass a value from form1.DataGridView1 to form2.Label1 when closing form1

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a function to get value from a `DataGridView`.

```
Private Function ItemaDataTransfer()
    Try
        Dim Purfrm As New Entr_PurchaseForm
        Dim i As Integer
        i = FindItemDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index
        If i > 0 Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FindItemDataGridView.Item(0, i).Value.ToString) Then

                Purfrm.ItemIDLabel.Text = FindItemDataGridView.Item(0, i).Value.ToString

            Else
                Purfrm.ItemIDLabel.Text = 0

            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As ApplicationException
        MessageBox.Show("Error" & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Function
```

Here is my form:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
Private Sub ItemaDataTransfer()
        Try
            Dim i As Integer = FindItemDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index
            If i > 0 Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FindItemDataGridView.Item(0, i).Value.ToString) Then
                    Entr_PurchaseForm.ItemIDLabel.Text = FindItemDataGridView.Item(0, i).Value.ToString
                Else
                    Entr_PurchaseForm.ItemIDLabel.Text = "0"
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error" & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```